# How many 4digit numbers can be written with $0,1,3,4,5,6,8,9$ and conditioned that numbers have to be greater than 4500

Tags: combinatorics

How many 4digit numbers can be written with $0,1,3,4,5,6,8,9$ and conditioned that numbers have to be greater than 4500 ?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is relatively simple.

You have a limited choice for the first digit: $0$, $1$, $3$ are forbidden. $4$ is allowed with a restriction on the second digit.

The second digit is free except when first digit is $4$. In that case second digit should be equal or greater than $5$.

I think with that you can proceed and finish...

Answer (score 1):

You have eight possible digits, so that's the same as the number of numbers *in base eight* that are greater than $3400_8$ and at most $7777_8$.

```
$ perl -le 'print 07777-03400'
```